# spring-security-core 2.0.3 spring-aop 2.0.8 cause NoSuchMethodError

Tags: linux, spring-security, spring-aop, bamboo, nosuchmethoderror

Using Maven to build my project under windows works fine, but when deploy it to Linux servers via bamboo, on two servers it seems ok but on third server I get a NoSuchMethodError regarding one of the spring libs. İf i remowe spring-aop:jar from war it works. İf it is because of different spring versions how to works on other two linux servers?

Has anyone come across this problem before, or have any advice on how I can debug this error further?

Any help would be appreciated.

library tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ pqis-op ---
[INFO] com.toyotatr.tmem.pqis:pqis-op:war:0.0.1.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.toyotatr.tmem.pqis:pqis-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.toyota.tme.jpa:jpa-support:jar:1.1tk:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-     annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.jsr107cache:jsr107cache:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core-tiger:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl104-over-slf4j:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO]
```

error

```
[07-05-2015 15:41:27:928] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext() - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-main.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1250)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:109)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: If you have more than one versions of the same jar bundled inside your WAR, you are likely to have problem of incorrect version of jar being loaded and result in such errors. I believe you have to adjust your dependency declarations in your POM to ensure you pickup one correct version for every jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem like the one that you described in the past. That weird behaviour is possible because the order of the class loading isn't guaranteed. So, it's possible that the same WAR file works on one server and fails on another one.

The easy way to debug that problem is using an IDE like eclipse or intellij and search for the `AopNamespaceUtils`class. If you find two or more occurrences of that class, you're able to find the jars that contain that class and remove those jars (the jars with the wrong version of the class) from the WAR file.

If you aren't able to find it with the IDE, you can enable the classloader debug log and check the differences between the servers that work/not work. (As you didn't mention the servlet container/application server that you're using, I can't point you to a guide to do that, but that is something easy to find using google).